# escaping single quoted javascript parameters in Razor's Html.Raw

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, escaping

so how can I quote a java script function parameters in Razor's Html.Raw helper?
In order to be able to invoke defined js function it looks like I need to have parameters single-quoted..

while output of NON escaped parameters:

```
@Html.Raw("<a onClick='copyRowValues(" + name + ", " + localTable + ", " + sqlName + ");' > " + name + " </a>");
```

translates like:

```
<a onclick="copyRowValues(ASN, ASN, ASN_RECORD_ID);">
```

which looks nice, but when those parameters for copyRowValues(...) js function are not single quoted, function is not being called.
so when I add single-quotes like this:

```
@Html.Raw("<a onClick='copyRowValues('" + name + "', '" + localTable + "', '" + sqlName + "');' > " + name + " </a>");
```

that produces:

```
<a 'asn_record_id');'="" 'asn',="" asn',="" onclick="copyRowValues(">
```

escaping with @ or \ just didn't work for me.
Thank you for straightforward solution!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the raw helper instead of just a `<a>` itself? I'm having trouble picturing a scenario where this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Does using double double-quotes work? e.g.

```
@Html.Raw("<a onClick=""copyRowValues('" + name + "', '" + localTable + "', '" + sqlName + "');"" > " + name + " </a>");
```

Comment: no, its syntactically bad and that approach I have tried as you can see in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not solution without Html.Raw() ? It's somehow obsollete approach to use it for generating the output html.

Try something like this:

```
<a onclick="copyRowValues(@name, @localTable, @sqlName)">@name</a>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You'd still need the single quotes though, like this: `copyRowValues('@name', '@localTable', '@sqlName')`

Comment: @NickCraver
actually that translates like:
`<a '@sqlname');'="" '@localtable',="" @name',="" onclick="copyRowValues("></a>`